# How to use embedded array in Vapor Postgres table?

Tags: postgresql, vapor

I need to use embedded array in `Fluent` Postgres table.

```swift
final class TempUser: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var Uuid: String
    var bookedSeats: [BookedSeat] // <- HERE
```

and

```swift
struct BookedSeat: Content {
    var price: String
    var sectorInd: Int
    var rowInd: Int
    var seatInd: Int
    var bookedUntil: Date
}
```

But get an error and warning:

```
[WARNING] [PostgreSQL] Could not determine PostgreSQL array data type: Array<BookedSeat>
[ ERROR ] PostgreSQLError.server.error.array_recv: wrong element type (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)
```

I did a custom solution, doing encoding decoding of the array manually:

```swift
func setBookedSeatsArray(bs: [BookedSeat]) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = try! encoder.encode(bs)
    let ret = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    self.bookedSeats = ret
}

func getGookedSeatsArray() -> [BookedSeat] {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let ret = try! decoder.decode([BookedSeat].self, from: self.bookedSeats)
    return ret
}
```

but I do not really like this solution.

Someone said: I need to conform entity to `PostgreSQLDataTypeStaticRepresentable`.

But I can not figure out how?

[image]

[image]